# List count index bug c#

Tags: c#

I'm try to manipulate a List in C# but i don't know why my list getting a error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

this is not logic, because index start at position 0, and i have 4 items.

So for checking index, i'm using Count < 3:

To reproduce this bug, here is a simple example with 1 textbox and 1 Button:

```
List<string> device = new List<string>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // check index
    if (device.Count < 3)
    {
        device.Add(textBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (device.Count == 3)
    {

        string ac = device.ElementAt(device.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("T")));
        string dc = device.ElementAt(device.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("E")));
        string fg = device.ElementAt(device.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("B")));
        string hi = device.ElementAt(device.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("G"))); // null 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
        MessageBox.Show(ac + "," + dc + "," + fg + " pushed to db table!!");
        //Console.WriteLine(ac + "," + dc + "," + fg + " pushed to db table!!");
    }
}
```

on the the last line, var **hi** getting this error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, could you explain me please what's wrong with my code?

i have found a solution,

Update :

```
    List<string> device = new List<string>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // check index
            device.Add(textBox1.Text);
            //textBox1.Clear();
            textBox1.Focus();

        if (device.Count < 4) return; 

        string ac = device.ElementAt(device.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("T")));
        string dc = device.ElementAt(device.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("E")));
        string fg = device.ElementAt(device.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("B")));
        string hi = device.ElementAt(device.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("G")));
       // string hi = device.FirstOrDefault(d => d.StartsWith(("G"))); //is null
        MessageBox.Show(ac + "," + dc + "," + fg + ", " + hi + " pushed to db table!!");
        //Console.WriteLine(ac + "," + dc + "," + fg + " pushed to db table!!");
    }
```

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: There's no words starting in `'G``?

Comment: What entries are in the device list?

Comment: if you have 4 items and want them all, it is Count < 4 (0 to 3)

Comment: @derloopkat thanks, but i have 3 items if i want to get the last items i need to add one more.

Answer (score 3):

FindIndex returns -1 in your line, because there is no index which starts with "G" in your list.

Look at this link for more details:
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-7.0)

Instead of your code, you can use:

```
var hi = device.SingleOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("G"));
```

If there is no match, then `hi` has the value `null`.

Based on the comment from **derloopkat**:

The index in the if needs 4 and not 3.

Comment: thank you for link and example, i have G in index but i need to add one more item to index to access them...

Comment: Ahh okay.. make sense. ;) But you should use the safe way, I mentioned.

Comment: if i change 3 to 4 i need to add 5 items to access to the 4, this is my problem actually...

Comment: yes, when i click on the button T are saved, E same, B same, G same, then i need to type 1 more to get my entire list i don't know if is Vs or app.

Comment: I think, that your current problem is another problem. Please create a new question for your new problem.